# Attaching confirmation popup to button element depending on ruby logic

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an `Add to Cart` button. I have multiple merchants set up and a user cannot have items from different merchants in the cart. I want to set it up so that if a user adds an item from another merchant, it will be added and all of the old items that aren't from the new merchant will be removed from the cart.

**offer.html.erb**

```
<button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right add-offer' type='button'>
   <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart'></span> Add to Cart
</button>
```

I want to display a javascript confirm prompt so that the user knows that he is about to remove all other items when the item is from a different merchant (`if current_item_merchant != cart.merchant`).

How do I add a confirm prompt to the button? Is this handled via javascript or does Rails already provide some kind of solution for this already?

If this is handled by Javascript, how do I add Rails conditional logic to my javascript code (referencing ruby variables)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
<% if current_item_merchant != cart.merchant %>
    <%= button_to "Add to cart", {}, confirm: "Are you sure?" %>
<% else %>
    <%= button_to "Add to cart" %>
<% end %>
```

Just change the button_to properties depending on the conditional. (Assuming you are using .erb

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out as well. I didn't realize button_to works in a form as well :)

Comment: Important: Rails >4.1 will just ignore this! Be sure to define it like `data: { confirm: "..." }`

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `button_to` helper, you can use unobtrusive Javascript to pop-up a confirmation dialog. Modify this snippet as you see fit:

```
<%= button_to "Add to Cart", data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

[Documentation here.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html)